# Ruby - constant initialisation with some function produces NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, initialization, constants

Let's consider following code:

```
class Try
 CONST = xxx("42")

 private_class_method def self.xxx(str)
   str.to_i
 end
end

puts Try::CONST
```

It produces an error: `` undefined method `xxx' for Try:Class (NoMethodError) ``

It seems that I cannot use a class private method to initialise a constant. The example is doing nothig actually, but it is a reproduction of an error I am facing trying to read data from file into the class constant.

Is it becuse ruby tries to initialize a constant before it get know about all methodes, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hint #1: at what point are you calling the method? Hint #2: at what point are you defining the method? Hint #3: which of those two points come first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. What you can't do is to assign the value of something that still hasn't been defined to something else in order to hold its value.

It has nothing to do with the method visibility because this works:

```
class Try
  private_class_method def self.xxx(str)
    str.to_i
  end
  CONST = xxx("42")
end

p Try::CONST
# 42
```

Comment: So, as I suspected, it depends on order of the code in the class. In this case, I don't like that private class method has to be defined before the public constant.
Thanks for quick answer!

Comment: In that case, it doesn't matter the visibility for the constant nor the method. But what's strange is you're using a constant to hold the value of a private method. It doesn't look like something to give you a big profit.